# delete shorter strings in text file

Tags: java, file

How can I delete shorter strings in a text file that looks like this:

```
987987
9879872938472
987234
234987234987
32423
```

I want to be able to delete the strings that are less than 5 characters.  I would like to know how to do this in terms of using Java.

Comment: *"(On separate lines)"*  Use code formatting.  Or more verbosely.  Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML. To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: First, you'll want to `split` the string, then you'll want to check each string's `length` and see if it's less than 5 (or `<`)...

Answer (score 1):

```
String string="987987 9879872938472 987234 234987234987 32423";
    String[] splitString=string.split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<splitString.length;i++){
        if(splitString[i].length()<5){
            continue;
        }
        //write to file 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you'd want something like this.

```
// to read in the file    
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("file"));

// read in each line and check to see if they are greater
// than 5 characters in length
while sc.hasNextLine(){
    String line = sc.nextLine().trim();
    if(line.length() >= 5) {
        System.out.println(line);
        // or code here to output to some file.
    }
}
```